# Manipulating icons in the table row based on condition

Tags: sapui5

I have the `sap.ui.table.Table` in XML view as below:

```xml
<Table id="testtable" xmlns="sap.ui.table"
  rows="{/testdata}"
  alternateRowColors="true">
  <columns>
    <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col1">
      <template>
        <m:Text text="{dataX}" wrapping="false" />
      </template>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col2">
      <template>
        <m:Text text="{dataY}" wrapping="false" />
      </template>
    </Column>
    <Column label="Col3">
      <template>
        <m:HBox>
          <core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="#007bff" />
          <core:Icon src="sap-icon://edit" color="#007bff" />
          <core:Icon src="sap-icon://print" color="#007bff" />
        </m:HBox>
      </template>
    </Column>
  </columns>
</Table>
```

[image: sample fig: (rough)]

Here what I am trying to achieve is for different rows I want to change the properties of Icons as:

[image: manipulated table]

To achieve this, I did something as:

Code below is what I tried for manipulating (not to get exactly as in image)

```js
var noOfrows = data.length; // data is here table rows data 
var tabItems = this.byId("testtable").getRows();
if (noOfrows != 1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfrows - 1; i++) {
    var cells = tabItems[i].getCells();
    cells[2].mAggregations.items[0].setColor("#000000");
    cells[2].mAggregations.items[1].setColor("#c2baba");
    cells[2].mAggregations.items[2].setColor("#000000");
  }
} else {
  var cells = tabItems[0].getCells();
  cells[2].mAggregations.items[0].setColor("#007bff");
  cells[2].mAggregations.items[1].setColor("#007bff");
  cells[2].mAggregations.items[2].setColor("#007bff");
}
```

This does the thing but I have read this to be very bad. I have no idea how I could do this in a proper way.

I am trying to accomplish this by keeping table, columns in XML view (if this is possible) as above instead of adding dynamically from controller.

The sample of data looks as:

```
var testdata = [{test: "A", data:'eg1'},
                {test: "B", data:'eg2'},
                {test: "C", data:'eg3'}]
```

Comment: What exactly is the condition in the app? I see from the code snippet that the icon colors should depend on the number of available rows. Is it what you need? Or was it just an example?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann  It is just an example sir, I am trying to manipulate the icon properties for each single row , for example for 1st row change icons with different color , for second row setting one icon visible false and keep other same as previous state.... the code i have tried works correctly when page is refreshed i don't understand why this is not working when just navigated (as may be I am using mAggregations which is bad ), hope you got my Q :) Is there a way i could achieve this ? i have been stuck here |:)

Comment: Are the icons visible, black or blue, enable based on some data that you have? Perhaps when dataX and dataY meet a certain condition? To answer YOUR question we need more info - giving you a generic solution may not help you. I.e. when should the icons be blue and when should they be black?

Comment: @Bernard Is that not possible based on rows simply , for eg: row 1 --> color black , row 2 --> invisible ....and so on ..... or I have a condition where the binding data of rows has a property say 'test' for each row ....and based on its value i want to change that respective row icons properties , hope it is clear :)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for answering! @Codenewbie If you target Fiori design guidelines, you might want to put the icons in the `rowActionTemplate`-aggregation of the table. The [`RowActionItem`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.table.RowActionItem) doesn't support setting custom colors though. Just an idea if the customer prefers consistent Fiori UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a worked example - it will move you towards where you need to go (as I would not put the formatting function in the controller but in a separate js file). Can do that later if you need me to.

Set you Icons colours to depend on the variable 'test' you allude to in your comment by calling the `setIconColour` function that returns a valid Icon colour.

```
<core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
```

Set a value for test in your data:

```
{"testdata": [
    { "dataX": 1, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 0},
    { "dataX": 2, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 2},
    { "dataX": 3, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 3},
    { "dataX": 4, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 1}
]}
```

Use the value of test to set the icon colour in a function (below is an example):

```
setIconColour: function (value) {
  if (value === 0) {
    return "Default";
  } else if (value === 1) {
    return "#007bff";
  } else if (value === 2) {
    return "Positive";
  } else if (value === 3) {
    return "Negative";
  } 
}
```

The icon colour will now be a function of the value of the variable 'test'.

[image]

Addition - code snippet included (THIS IS NOT HOW YOU BUILD A SAPUI5 APP - this is to illustrate this with a WORKING example from which to learn or with which you can play)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>example conditional formatter</title>
        <script
         src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns:m="sap.m"
                xmlns="sap.ui"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
              <Table id="testtable" xmlns="sap.ui.table"
                rows="{/testdata}"
                alternateRowColors="true">
                <columns>
                  <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col1">
                    <template>
                      <m:Text text="{dataX}" wrapping="false" />
                    </template>
                  </Column>
                  <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col2">
                    <template>
                      <m:Text text="{dataY}" wrapping="false" />
                    </template>
                  </Column>
                  <Column label="Col3">
                    <template>
                      <m:HBox>
                        <core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
                        <core:Icon src="sap-icon://edit" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
                        <core:Icon src="sap-icon://print" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
                      </m:HBox>
                    </template>
                  </Column>
                </columns>
              </Table>
            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
                ], function (Controller, JSONModel, XMLModel) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () {

                            var that = this;
                            let model = new JSONModel(this.getData());
                            this.getView().setModel(model);
                         },
                       setIconColour: function (value) {
                            if (value === 0) {
                              return "Default";
                            } else if (value === 1) {
                              return "#007bff";
                            } else if (value === 2) {
                              return "Positive";
                            } else if (value === 3) {
                              return "Negative";
                            } 
                          },

                       getData: function(){
                          return {"testdata": [
                            { "dataX": 1, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 0},
                            { "dataX": 2, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 2},
                            { "dataX": 3, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 3},
                            { "dataX": 4, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 1}
                            ]};
                          }
                })
                });
                

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: understood sir !! such an Amazing idea , I was thinking of putting formatting function in controller as you mentioned , if we put so , how would we embed in controller ?

Comment: You would add the above function (setIconColour) into the controller - that simple. Because the controller is referenced as the controller for the View you would have access to the function. (i.e. just cut and paste the setIconColour into your current controller (add a comma if necessary)

Comment: You can influence other properties (like 'visible') in the same manner.

Comment: sure sir , in the xml the format is same ? color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" or any changes here i have to make ?

Comment: yes, just like that (your XML View presumably references the controller into which you inserted the above function)

Comment: ..@Bernard Sir, May i know how the value passed is value of test in setIconColour , and also , if there is a scenario where i want to set colors only to all the data except arr[arr.length-1] and for this row a different set of icon properties , i have tried what you have mentioned but stuck on value passed , sorry while looking at the answer i understood but on implementing i am confused ....also i have updated the Q with sample data on which I'm checking the condition :)

Comment: when you specify path in the XML View it 'selects' the variable. When a formatter is associated (i.e. setIconColour) this function accepts a value (called value but it could have a difference variable name). The value of 'value' will be test. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: ..@Bernard I understood as , for each index of array , value of 'test' to be sent as value to setIconColour ....for this I should loop over ?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood correctly. Each row will present its value (of the variable 'test') to setIconColour and this function returns a Colour based on that value

Comment: I am stuck on How `test` value will be passed to function ? each time in the array the value varies for each index , so i am confused here , hope you got my Q

Comment: look at the JSON payload in my answer above - the value of 'test' is set differently

Comment: yes i have seen sir, so value test value is directly sent to `setIconColour` ?

Comment: I have seen sir, now got the clarity , would ask if stuck again , thank you :)

Comment: sir , I have set the model with alias name , how would path is referred as ? for eg : `this.getView().setModel(model,"aliasname");` then path for icon color in xml should be as ?

Comment: also i want to add properties as per rows and condition sir ...In E.g. for sample , if we bind to table 4 rows would come , now based on `row number` and the `test` value (eg: `1st row` and `test` vlaue --> apply color , `last row` and `test` value apply different color) .....hope you understood my Q...

Comment: Could you formulate a new question and reduce it to what you are stuck on - that will help - it will focus the thread and limit assistance to the specific thing(s) you are stuck on. I am getting lost in the referencing here. Hope that makes sense

Comment: sure sir , i thought of same but same q if i repeat may be community closes , i would add sir

Comment: tried the same but it didn't reflect sir ,and that condition im facing i would ask a new one ...

Comment: you need to insert that named model everywhere where it needs to be

Comment: sir to have more clarity I opened a new Q here...... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788717/manipulating-icon-properties-based-on-row-index-row-number-of-table-and-a-prop

Comment: @Codenewbie - i did respond on the new post

Answer (score 0):

Add Tag Like below:

```
<core:Icon id="tblColIcon"
  src="{path:'Salary', formatter:'.formatter.setIconFF'}"
  tooltip="{path:'Salary', formatter:'.formatter.setIconToolTipFF'}" 
  color="{path:'Salary', formatter:'.formatter.setIconColorFF'} >
```

In `formatter.js` you can define your condition and return the value.