# Manipulating Icon properties based on row index (row number) of table and a property of Model Data

Tags: sapui5

I have the table in XML view as:

```
<Table id="testtable" xmlns="sap.ui.table"
  rows="{/testdata}"
  alternateRowColors="true">
  <columns>
    <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col1">
      <template>
        <m:Text text="{dataX}" wrapping="false" />
      </template>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" label="Col2">
      <template>
        <m:Text text="{dataY}" wrapping="false" />
      </template>
    </Column>
    <Column label="Col3">
      <template>
        <m:HBox>
                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://edit" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://print" color="{path: 'test', formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
        </m:HBox>
      </template>
    </Column>
  </columns>
</Table>
```

From the prev Q in SO , I could able to manipulate icon properties using formatter as :

controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
                ], function (Controller, JSONModel, XMLModel) {
                    "use strict";

                return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                    onInit : function () {

                        var that = this;
                        let model = new JSONModel(this.getData());
                        this.getView().setModel(model);
                     },
                   setIconColour: function (value) {
                        if (value === 0) {
                          return "Default";
                        } else if (value === 1) {
                          return "#007bff";
                        } else if (value === 2) {
                          return "Positive";
                        } else if (value === 3) {
                          return "Negative";
                        } 
                      },

                   getData: function(){
                      return {"testdata": [
                        { "dataX": 1, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 0},
                        { "dataX": 2, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 2},
                        { "dataX": 3, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 3},
                        { "dataX": 4, "dataY": "testdata", "test": 1}
                        ]};
                      }
            })
            });
```

[image: Table would look as]

Here May I know how can I check multiple conditions for e.g.

1) Manipulating color properties based on `test` value and `row number (index)` (or) which index of array and its corresponding `test` value

from above I could think as passing multiple params to setIconColour (row/index no. and test) values If I'm not wrong ,

May I know how could I do this , Hope its clear :)

Comment: Pass multiple params to your formatter.

Comment: hey @Marc , i have got this idea but may i know how could i do this... a sample that would lead me do rest :)

Comment: Have you tried googling `sapui5 formatter multiple params`?

Comment: yes @Marc suggested to use `parts` , but i am stuck how could i pass index of array /model as second param

Comment: @Codenewbie Unfortunately, UI5 does not support passing the current index of the row to the formatter. It's also a very unusual requirement. What is the purpose for this? Seems like we're dealing with an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Actually the purpose is based on rows i.e., if the data is just one row , i want to manipulate icon properties (with `test` condition) , and if it has say 5 rows , the last row(for 5th row(with `test` condition)) i want to manipulate  icon properties for 5th row differently and other 4(with `test` condition) differently , hope its clear

Comment: @Codenewbie Ok, could you update the question accordingly? Having `dataX` was quite confusing which led to the answer below whereas the actual goal was without the `dataX`, am I right?

Comment: exactly , `dataX` is not required here in that place i have to check as i mentioned in above comment sit , i have asked accordingly in Q too sir :)

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I am able to get out of this sir , but May I know when is formatter function is actually called ? soon after onInit method ? What if i set model in _onRouteMatched , if i did so  formatter gets null as param , may i know how can I call formatter after _onRouteMatched method ?

Comment: @Codenewbie About the last question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806227/5846045 explains when the formatter is called and what to do about it.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann read the post sir , so to my Q , first i need to check inside formatter function whether the params exits(not null) , if no just return --> now after init , _onroute gets called where model is set to view and then again formatter is called ? this is confusing sir, im sorry as i am setting model in _onRoute , i got this confusion as rest all examples set in init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multivariable formatter use this syntax for the formatted control:

```
<core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="{ parts : [ 'test', 'dataX' ], formatter: '.setIconColour'}" />
```

The function needs to be adjusted to:

```
setIconColour: function (testValue, dataX) {

  if (testValue === 0 && dataX === 1) {
    return "Default";
  } else if (testValue === 0 && dataX === 2) {
    return "#ff0000";                            
  } else if (testValue === 1) {
    return "#007bff";
  } else if (testValue === 2) {
    return "Positive";
  } else if (testValue === 3) {
    return "Negative";
  } 
},
```

Comment: Sir , here what I'm trying to do is for only last row or if there is only one row  i want to show different color for icons , may i know how to achieve this ?

Comment: make the color for the different icons depend on separate variables